# Two rows in a single table cell?

Tags: html, html-table

I like to add three rows in a single `td` table cell by using `HTML5`. I've tried adding a new table element inside the `td`, like this:

```html
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Lorem ipsum
                </td>
                <td>
                    Lorem ipsum
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Row 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Row 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I get two rows, but this just breaks my markup.

Any alternative solutions? Maybe with flexbox?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You don't need a table inside a table.  `tr`s with empty `td`s where needed should do the trick.  This can also be done with flexbox, but use a table if you are presenting tabluar data.  If it's for layout, try flexbox.

Comment: Why does it break your markup ? You don't want to use too much tags or it breaks other rows ?

Comment: and why simple <p> or <div> is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you may try, I don't know if it's the thing you want but still.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan=2>
                Lorem ipsum
            </td>
            <td rowspan=2>
                Lorem ipsum
            </td>
            <td>
               Row 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
               Row 2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from `qocu` kind of works as well, but I don't want to add `rowspan`s everywhere. So I ended up using the almighty flexbox. Not sure about which versions of IE this method supports, but luckily I do not have to support anything prehistoric. The solution:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="display: flex">
            <td>
                Lorem ipsum
            </td>
            <td>
                Lorem ipsum
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
                    <span>Row 1</span>
                    <span>Row 2</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```